# Using SftpOutboundGateway to list remote files in spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch

I am using spring batch partitioning and i would like to send a file list to each partition for processing.
I need to know how to invoke SftpOutboundGateway and get the list of remote files names from the spring batch Partitioner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's all you need to do, consider just using `FtpRemoteFileTemplate.list()` or even `Session.listNames()`.